# Programmatically Enable LG Gram Laptop Keyboard Backlight at Startup

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I can't find anywhere how to automatically have the backlight turn on at either startup or after sleeping/hibernation after triggering a login event.

Is it possible to turn this on via a registry setting, using a .bat file, or PowerShell, and/or with Task Scheduler?

When I log into Windows, I would like for the keyboard backlight to be turned on.

**LG Gram laptop 16**

Comment: Hello, what did you try? You could for instance press the key combo for turning it on.

Comment: First, someone needs to know what you normally do to activate the backlight. Pressing a key, for example, might be scripted. Second, many notebooks have settings for the keyboard backlight that maybe can directly help you - check your BIOS and the software/tools LG offers for this notebook.

Comment: To turn the light on its easy by pressing Fn+F8 but that has to be done manually and during the night when booting it's harder to see on the eyes so I want to have the computer boot with the keyboard backlight always on VS having to do this manually...

Comment: @RTG: While scripting *normal* key inputs isn't hard, its actually not possible to script the FN key. Not even the default windows on-screen keyboard, that *does* show this key, can make use of it. So, you might find another way of triggering the backlights? What are the options for your keyboard backlight in your BIOS?

Comment: Might sound stupid, but if you want to change you can't *see* the keys at night - maybe you might *feel* them, just a small piece of transparent tape on this keys might be enough.

Comment: [This source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.6/admin-guide/laptops/lg-laptop.html) indicates that the backlight key combination produces an `F16` key code. You could try using an AutoHotkey script to send this key code on startup. Unfortunately, I cannot test this, since I don't have an LG Gram.

Answer (score 0):

Not programatically but it's a solution...

1. LG Control Center (Press windows key to search for this)
2. System Settings > Hardware
3. Keyboard Backlight: Select "Disable"
4. Brightness options are Off / Low / High